# Is Chrome Browser/ Computer compromised by KMSPico?

Tags: windows, virus, chrome, trojan, virus-removal

I recently installed a new windows key for my friend.
He was using a hack program previously, known as Auto KMS. So after new keys installation, I used Windows defender to remove AutoKMS program. The defender found the kms program in

> C:/Windows/System32/Tasks/

which I think the hack program needed for bypassing windows licensing. However, the Auto KMS program was also present in below location which is a private directory for Google chrome.

[image: windows defender notification]

1. Why would a hack program to bypass windows licensing be present in Google Chrome's user data folder?
2. Was this hack program also spying on Chrome history, cookies and stuff like banking websites?
   How does this even work, Can a trojan program copy its payload in data files of chrome and chrome unknowingly loads it in memory?
3. Even though we have scanned full pc with windows defender and did an offline scan, should we be wary that the virus/trojan is still present?

The Auto KMS program was also present in the exclusion list of Windows defender. I removed it before scanning the whole computer.

Comment: I would suggest that this is just the cache of the browser, i.e. its in there together with many other things visited by the user.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Can you explain a little bit. Why Windows defender flagged it if it is just a cache?

Comment: Just because it is in the cache does not mean that the file is not dangerous when explicitly executed by the user. But that does not mean that the system is infected or Chrome is infected, but only that there is a file downloaded, which gets dangerous when executed.